# how to do the list subtraction using multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using the following code, to do the list subtraction.

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Y = [4,5]

# to find the elements which in X but not in Y
result = [e for e in X if e not in Y]
# expected result: [1,2,3,6]
```

since there are millions of element in X and Y,

the subtraction operation is very slow,

single CPU usage reached 100% (left other 10+ CPUs usage 0%), maybe using multiprocessing may improve the situation.

how to do it using multiprocessing in Python?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
????
pool = Pool(11)
pool.map(?, ?)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "list subtraction"? Can you show how you would do this in a non-concurrent way?

Comment: How slow is it, and what's the type of `Y`? Most likely yet another XY problem.

Comment: So is `Y` a `list` of millions of elements?

Comment: @HeapOverflow yep, both X and Y has millions of elements. the result maybe contain thousands of elements.

Comment: Lol... did you rename your variables to X and Y because I said it's likely an XY problem? That's not what that means. [This is](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: single CPU usage reached 100% (left other 10+ CPUs usage 0%),  using multiprocessing may improve the situation.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  `[e for e in X if e not in Y]` means using a loop of X to find the elements which in X but not in Y.

Comment: @CharlesBao Thanks for adding the code to show what you are trying to do.

Comment: Stop thinking about multiprocessing and make `Y` a `set` already.

Comment: fun fact: I'm testing `[e for e in X if e not in set(Y)]` for both X and Y with million of items and it crashes.

Comment: @mathfux Why would you do that, though?

Comment: @Heap Overflow just for fun

Comment: @mathfux Rather strange that that crashes. What are your X and Y? (Note for others to be clear: This is of course *not* how I meant it, converting to set over and over again.)

Comment: both are 1000000 random integers.

Comment: @mathfux Can you share the code and the error message?

Comment: @HeapOverflow set converting does improve my situation a lot, thanks.

Comment: `X = [randint(0,10000000) for n in range(1000000)]`
`Y = [randint(0,10000000) for n in range(1000000)]`
`[e for e in X if e not in set(Y)]`
This loops forever because `set(Y)` is recalculates in each iteration. So be careful:)

Comment: @mathfux You said it crashes and now you say it loops forever? Which one is it?

Comment: @mathfux Still wondering... did it really crash?

Comment: No. It looped forever, no errors found :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to read the [documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) about efficiency of `e in X`. If X is a list, it takes `O(n)` time which is really slow if you use it for all the items. Unlike checking items for sets which is instant. For further optimisation I would use [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) because it does loops just faster.

```
Z = set(Y)
result = [e for e in X if e not in Z]
```

Comment: @Heap Overflow why aren't you convinced?

Comment: Well, it's not that much faster as I expected but speed up is obvious. I have taken two lists `[randint(0,1000000) for x in range(5000000)]` and measured times of `Z=set(y); [e for e in X if e not in Z]` vs `np.setdiff1d(X,Y).tolist()`. It resulted in 2.7 and 1.7 secs.

Comment: Nice, thanks! I was already wondering how it would look with numpy (I don't know it much and didn't know `setdiff1d`).

Comment: I tried those as well now and got 2.43 and 1.75 seconds. And 2.28 seconds for `set(X) - set(Y)`.

Comment: set(X) - set(Y) is just `set`, it doesn't preserve order of items

Comment: Yeah but your NumPy solution doesn't preserve order, either.